# Each loop of an if statement, save to a different variable

Tags: python, variables, count, split, char

I'm trying to take the frequency of letters in a document and then split them up into individual variables so I can turn them into percentages. The problem I'm having is that the variable var1 gets rewritten every time the if statement goes round... I'm not sure how I can get each of the 26 characters' frequencies to be written into separate variables, so that I can turn them into percentages and use each percentage individually.

This is my code, and var1 ends up printing as the last or least common letter in the file:

```
def freq():
    info = input("File Name")
    filehandle = open(info, "r")
    data = filehandle.read().upper()
    char_counter = collections.Counter(data)
    for char, count in char_counter.most_common():
        if char in string.ascii_uppercase:
            s = (str(count))
            my_tokens = s.split("|")
            print(my_tokens)
            global var1
            var1 = my_tokens[0]

freq()
print(var1)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I am slightly at a loss for what to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dictionary` where your char is the key and the value is the number of occurrences, just like this:

```
import collections

def freq():
    var1 = dict()
    info = input("File Name")
    filehandle = open(info, "r")
    data = filehandle.read().upper()
    char_counter = collections.Counter(data)
    for char, count in char_counter.most_common():
        if char in data.upper():
            s = (str(count))
            my_tokens = s.split("|")
            print(my_tokens)
            var1[char] = my_tokens[0]
    return var1

var1 = freq()
print(var1)
```

You can read more about the use of dictionaries here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a `dict`:

```
def freq():
    info = input("File Name")
    filehandle = open(info, "r")
    data = filehandle.read().upper()
    char_counter = collections.Counter(data)
    result = {}
    for char, count in char_counter.most_common():
        if char in string.ascii_uppercase:
            s = (str(count))
            my_tokens = s.split("|")
            print(my_tokens)
            result[char] = my_tokens[0]

result = freq()
print(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

Store each char freq into a hash (map) where key is char itself and value is integer. Increment integer value per char encountered

Comment: In python, you would use [dictionary](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm).